# Write macro for Increment enteries in SQL script

Tags: sql, editor, notepad++, firebird

I want to add a macro such that in following table

```
abc 2296 def  
abc 2297 def  
abc 2298 def   
abc 2299 def
```

these entries get incremented like -

```
abc 4301 def  
abc 4302 def  
abc 4303 def  
abc 4304 def
```

Any idea how I could i do that? I'm creating a SQL script. If there is any other editor apart from notepad ++  which can work for this then i dont have any issue in using that.

**@ALL - Whomsoever have downvoted this question - please put your notedown in comments or answer why its so.. This is not a joke, seriously i found this thing a bit trouble and that's why i put it question here .. and it's not something irrelevant. Please mind next time downvoting someone's post may be it's an easier for you but not everyone is genious.**

Ok. I'm able to move my data to excel. Now i've all values to be incremented in same column. Now how should i go ahead in excel ?

Comment: Are the `abc` and `def` always the same? Why not post your SQL and see if anyone can help you edit that, rather than resort to editor macros to generate a sequence of numbers?

Comment: I'm new to macros so i thought why dont give it a try if it can do that..

Comment: yes atleast for 20 lines they are same.

Comment: @Rohit A macro is good for automating a repetitive task - but notepad++ is an editor. I don't believe it'll do the arithmetic for you on the numbers, unless there's a plug-in somewhere that will provide that functionality.

Comment: Ok, so something else which can work for the same /??? as updating each entry one by one makes me feel like i'm a data entry operator which i dont want to do..

Comment: @Rohit - I'd suggest Excel, or something similar. Does your SQL scripting language not provide support for variables and loops though?

Comment: Oh oh oh everyone wasted his time on Rohit ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the options:
 1. Using Console application: Create an application which takes the sql script file as input stream, specify the range of the number which needs to be updated and provide the increment to be done. Output stream will provide the desired result. Will provide the code soon.

1. Using Notepad++, Excel. Copy Paste whole script in Excel. Now go to Data -> Text to column. All Id's would come in a column. Now update the cell with formula =ColumnRow + . Now merge all cells in one column. Copy/Paste script to sql manager :) ...

Answer (score 1):

If you have awk available then this is really easy: `awk '{print $1, $2+2005, $3}'`

```
$ cat data.dat
abc 2296 def
abc 2297 def
abc 2298 def
abc 2299 def
$ awk '{print $1, $2+2005, $3}' < data.dat
abc 4301 def
abc 4302 def
abc 4303 def
abc 4304 def
```

awk and other UNIX tools are available for Windows in [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Would Excel work for what you need?

Comment: Nopes, i'm writing a big sql script. excel wont work for that

Comment: I agree with this suggestion. I've used Excel to help me build SQL strings before and without having to resort to Excel functions - just cell formulas. I'm a great fan of notepa++ but I think Excel wins out for this problem

Comment: well here is my one script line 

INSERT INTO TBLABC (ID, MODELNUMBERBASE, MODELNUMBERBASEVISUALID, MODELNUMBERBASESTRINGID, DESCRIPTIONVISUALID, DESCRIPTIONSTRINGID, CUSTOMPRICE, ISMODELINACTIVE, ISMODELVIRTUAL, MAXPOWER, VOLTAGETYPEID, APPEARANCETYPE, APPEARANCEVALUE, SYSTEMTYPELISTID, REQUIRES, PRODUCTID, PRICEGROUPTYPEID, NAMEVISUALID, STRINGID, PRODUCTTYPEID, LONGDESCRIPTIONSTRINGID, LONGDESCRIPTIONID) VALUES ('2296', 'ABC', '9', '17363', '10', '8404', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 18, 'TwoB', '2', '0', NULL, '1', NULL, NULL, '8', '15255', '10');

Comment: NOW HOW COME DO I BRING IT TO EXCEL ?? WHEN I SIMPLY TRY TO COPY PASTE IT EVERYTHING COMES IN SINGLE CELL ...

Comment: @CResults - I agree. notepad++ is the wrong tool here. @Rohit - it would be helpful to edit your question to include your SQL.

Comment: You could import as CSV?

Comment: Once in Excel you can split out to multiple cells using menu: Data | Text To Columns. It is helpful to have a unique separator (e.g. TAB, Comma, | ).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [EXECUTE STATEMENT](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-psql-execstat.html)

Any number of data rows returned  This form – analogous to “FOR SELECT ... DO” – is used with SELECT statements that may return a multi-row dataset.

Syntax:

```
FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT <select-statement> INTO <var> [, <var> ...]
DO <compound-statement>

<select-statement>  ::=  Any SELECT statement. 
<var>               ::=  A PSQL variable, optionally preceded by “:”
```

you can see [example](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-psql-execstat.html#langrefupd15-psql-execstat-multirow)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a macro to simply insert the text "+2005" after the number. This will be evaluated by the DB (although it does depend on exactly what SQL you are generating). In the case of the SQL in the Excel answer comment you'd likely need to change to an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ..., 3456+2005, ...` to get the evaluation to work.